# How to read values from array list from another class and get output depending on user input?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I'm trying to figure out how to get values of an array list from another class and print certain values depending on user input.

For example, firstly a user is asked to provide a location, once they enter a location, it has to read the user input and output the results according to the location.[an image is provided about the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsBef.png).

For some reason it doesn't output the correct values from array list.
Could you please help me out?

This is my code for reading values from array list.

```
    public class Program {
    ArrayList<Properties> property = Properties.getMelbnbProperty();
    int i = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < (property.size());) {
        System.out.println(property.get(i));
        break;
    }
    
    ArrayList<Properties> output = Properties.getMelbnbProperty();
        if(Properties.getMelbnbProperty().contains(choice)) {
            output.addAll(Properties.getMelbnbProperty());
        }
    } }
```

This is my code for array list.

```
public class Properties {
public static ArrayList<Properties> getMelbnbProperty() {
    // Below is an arraylist where I have stored the Melbnb data
                ArrayList<Properties> property = new ArrayList<Properties>();
                property.add(new Properties("Private room in the heart of Southbank"));
                property.add(new Properties("Spacious bedroom in a cosy apartment in South Yarra\n"));
                property.add(new Properties("Ensuite room with great views"));
                property.add(new Properties("Single room next to Carlton Gardens"));
                property.add(new Properties("Studio close to Melbourne CBD"));
                property.add(new Properties("1-bedroom CBD view suite near Melbourne Central and RMIT"));
                property.add(new Properties("Stylish two bedroom in CBD"));
                property.add(new Properties("Sky high studio with amazing views"));
                property.add(new Properties("Budget accommodation bunk beds"));
                property.add(new Properties("A beautiful room near Marvel Stadium")); 
                
                return property;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided in your question post is incomplete and in a way doesn't make sense to what your image displays. I do however understand what you are trying to accomplish but the way I see it your properties class is somewhat under-nourished.

I don't know if this is the intentional purpose but your `for` loop:

```
int i = 1;
for(i = 1; i < (property.size());) {
    System.out.println(property.get(i));
    break;
}
```

is designed to pull out **1** object from the `property` ArrayList. This loop is completely unnecessary since just supplying an index value of **1** to the **ArrayList#get()** method does exactly the same thing and is only a single line of code, for example:

```
System.out.println(property.get(1));
```

I say this because your `for` loop *initializer* starts at index **1**, there is no *iterator* for the loop, and you apply the `break` statement directly after the display of the object within the ArrayList.

To access all elements within the ArrayList (your post indicates) you would need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(properties.get(i));
}
```

Or you can use:

```
for (String props: properties) {
    System.out.println(props);
}
```

To be honest, what you are showing for code in grossly underdeveloped. I don't want to come across as insulting but it's obvious that you are not showing as much as you should be and therefore it is extremely difficult to provide you with any concrete solution to your problem. For this reason, I think it is just easier to provide you with a working demo console application which would allow you to perhaps grasp some concepts from.

The runnable code below consists of two specific classes, the start up class named **SimpleBNBDemo** which contains the `main()` method and the **Properties** class which allows you to instantiate instances of different BNB properties. As you can see, the **Properties** class is somewhat more fulfilled than the class you provided in your question post. Take the time to read through the code and try to follow its flow. Do keep in mind, although runnable this is only a Demo application and is in now way a complete works. I personally would never hard-code fill an ArrayList with Object data. This data should come from and or saved to a file system or database. However, for demo purposes this will suffice.

The **SimpleBNBDemo** class:

```
public class SimpleBNBDemo {

    // Field variables
    public final static String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    public final static java.util.Scanner USER_INPUT = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    // class member variable
    private Properties prop = new Properties();
    private final String line = "------------------------------------------------";
    private int pwAttempts = 0;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Started this way to avoid the need for statics
        new SimpleBNBDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* Create Properties instances...
           You can do this with whatever means you like.  */
        java.util.List<Properties> properties = prop.getProperties();
        properties.add(new Properties("Southbank Mannor", "Room", "Private room in the heart of Southbank.", "South", 86.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Yarra House", "Room", "Spacious bedroom in a cosy apartment in South Yarra.", "South", 74.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Ensuite Haven", "Room", "Ensuite room with great views.", "West", 65.50d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Carlton Place", "Room", "Single room next to Carlton Gardens.", "South", 78.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Melbourne Studio", "Studio", "Studio close to Melbourne CBD.", "East", 78.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Melbourne Delight", "Room", "1-bedroom CBD view suite near Melbourne Central and RMIT.", "North", 135.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("CBD House", "Suit", "Stylish two bedroom in CBD.", "West", 100.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Sky-High", "Studio", "Sky high studio with amazing views.", "North", 95.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Budgeteer", "Room", "Budget accommodation bunk beds.", "South", 65.00d, true));
        properties.add(new Properties("Stadium House", "Room", "A beautiful room near Marvel Stadium.", "East", 95.00d, true));

        println("Welcome to MelBNB" + LS + line);
        println();

        // Menu 1 - Main Menu
        String choice = "";
        String[] locations = prop.getAllLocations();
        if (locations.length == 0) {
            printErr("No BNB's with Location in database yet!");
            return;
        }
        while (choice.isEmpty()) {
            println("Select from Main Menu:");
            println("  1) List all Accomodations");
            println("  2) Search by location");
            println("  3) Browse by type of accomodation");
            println("  4) Filter by rating");
            println("  5) Rate an accomodation");
            println("  6) Exit (quit)");
            print("Please choose: -> ");
            choice = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            // Validate Entry...switch/case works great for input validation.
            switch (choice) {
                case "1":
                    listAllAccomodations();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    searchByLocation();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    searchByAccomodationType();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    searchByRating();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    rateAnAccomodation();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    break;
                case "~admin~":
                    adminMenu();
                    break;
                case "~admin attempts reset~":
                    pwAttempts = 0;
                    println();
                    break;
                default:
                    println("Invalid Entry (" + choice + ")! Try again..." + LS);
            }
            // Was 'Exit' (4) selected?
            if (choice.equals("6")) {
                // Break out of loop to end application.
                println(LS + "Thank you for visiting MelBNB,  Bye-Bye." + LS);
                break;
            }
            choice = "";  // Reset 'choice' to be empty in order to loop again..
        }
    }

    private void adminMenu() {
        String pwrd = "";
        while (pwrd.isEmpty()) {
            if (pwAttempts >= 3) {
                println(LS + "Admin Menu is NOT Available!" + LS + "To many failed "
                      + "consecutive password attempts!" + LS + "Only " + pwAttempts 
                      + " consecutive attempts are allowed." + LS);
                return;
            }
            print(LS + "Please enter Admin Password (c to cancel): --> ");
            pwrd = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            if (pwrd.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                println();
                return;
            }

            int psum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pwrd.length(); i++) {
                psum += pwrd.charAt(i);
            }
            if (psum != 624) {
                pwAttempts++;
                println("Invalid Password! Try again...");
                pwrd = "";
            }
        }
        
        pwAttempts = 0;
        println();
        println("***********************************************");
        println("***  Administrative options would go here!  ***");
        println("***        Press Enter To Continue          ***");
        println("***********************************************");
        String nothing = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
    }

    private void listAllAccomodations() {
        println(LS + "All Available Accomodations:");
        println("----------------------------");
        int cntr = 0;
        String underline = "";
        for (Properties pp : prop.getProperties()) {
            cntr++;
            String str = pp.toStringTable(pp, cntr == 1);
            underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(str.length(), "="));
            println(str);
            if (cntr == 15) {
                println("<- Press Enter To Continue ->");
                String nuthin = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
                cntr = 0;
            }
        }
        println(underline + LS);
        
    }
    
    private void searchByLocation() {
        String[] locationTypes = prop.getAllLocations();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(locationTypes);

        String locationChoice = "";
        while (locationChoice.isEmpty()) {
            println();
            println("Select the desired location:");
            int i = 0;
            for ( ; i < locationTypes.length; i++) {
                println("  " + (i + 1) + ") " + locationTypes[i]);
            }
            println("  " + (i + 1) + ") Cancel");
            print("Please choose: -> ");
            locationChoice = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            // Validate Entry...
            if (!locationChoice.matches("[1-" + (locationTypes.length + 1) + "]")) {
                println("Invalid Entry (" + locationChoice + ")! Try again..." + LS);
                locationChoice = "";
            }
        }
        if (locationChoice.equals(String.valueOf(locationTypes.length + 1))) {
            println();
            return;
        }
        String location = locationTypes[Integer.valueOf(locationChoice)-1];
        java.util.List<Properties> p = prop.getPropertiesByLocation(location);
        if (p.isEmpty()) {
            println("No accomodations available in the " + location + " area!" + LS);
            return;
        }
        String str = "Available accomodation within the " + location + " area:";
        println(LS + str);
        println(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(str.length(), "-")));
        int cntr = 0;
        for (Properties pp : p) {
            cntr++;
            println(pp.toStringTable(pp, cntr == 1));
        }
        println(line + LS);
    }

    private void searchByAccomodationType() {
        String[] accTypes = prop.getAllAccomodationTypes();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(accTypes);

        String accChoice = "";
        while (accChoice.isEmpty()) {
            println();
            println("Select the desired accomodation type:");
            int i = 0;
            for ( ; i < accTypes.length; i++) {
                println("  " + (i + 1) + ") " + accTypes[i]);
            }
            println("  " + (i + 1) + ") Cancel");
            print("Please choose: -> ");
            accChoice = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            // Validate Entry...
            if (!accChoice.matches("[1-" + (accTypes.length + 1) + "]")) {
                println("Invalid Entry (" + accChoice + ")! Try again..." + LS);
                accChoice = "";
            }
        }
        if (accChoice.equals(String.valueOf(accTypes.length + 1))) {
            println();
            return;
        }
        String acc = accTypes[Integer.valueOf(accChoice)-1];
        java.util.List<Properties> p = prop.getPropertiesByAccomodationType(acc);
        if (p.isEmpty()) {
            println("No accomodation type of " + acc + " is  available!" + LS);
            return;
        }
        String str = "Available accomodation that are of type '" + acc + "':";
        println(LS + str);
        println(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(str.length(), "-")));
        int cntr = 0;
        for (Properties pp : p) {
            cntr++;
            println(pp.toStringTable(pp, cntr == 1));
        }
        println(line + LS);
    }

    private void searchByRating() {
        String rateChoice = "";
        while (rateChoice.isEmpty()) {
            println();
            println("Enter the desired accomodation rating (1 to 5);");
            print(  "Enter c to cancel. Desired Rating: --> ");
            rateChoice = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            if (rateChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                return;
            }
            // Validate Entry...
            if (!rateChoice.matches("[1-5]")) {
                println("Invalid Entry (" + rateChoice + ")! Try again..." + LS);
                rateChoice = "";
            }
        }

        int rating = Integer.valueOf(rateChoice);
        java.util.List<Properties> p = prop.getPropertiesByRating(rating);
        if (p.isEmpty()) {
            println("No accomodation available with the rating of " + rating + "!" + LS);
            return;
        }
        String str = "Available accomodation with a rating of '" + rating + "':";
        println(LS + str);
        println(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(str.length(), "-")));
        int cntr = 0;
        for (Properties pp : p) {
            cntr++;
            println(pp.toStringTable(pp, cntr == 1));
        }
        println(line + LS);
    }

    private void rateAnAccomodation() {
        /* Displayed ratings are always the AVERAGE of all ratings
           provided for that particular propety. This is done within
           the 'Properties.addRating()' method. For this reason and
           for other obvious reasons the Properties List should be
           saved to either a file or a database. If this is not done
           then all added or modified data will be lost when the
           application closes. The Properties List data should NOT
           be hard-coded. It should be loaded in when the application
           starts and saved to storage when data is added or modified.
        */
        String[] pNames = prop.getAllPropertyNames();

        String nameToRate = "";
        while (nameToRate.isEmpty()) {
            println(LS + "Enter the name of the accomodation you want to rate:");
            print(  "Enter 'c' to cancel. Rating: --> ");
            nameToRate = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            if (nameToRate.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                return;
            }
            // Validate Entry............................
            if (nameToRate.isEmpty()) {
                println("Invalid Entry! You must enter a Name! Try again...");
                nameToRate = "";
                continue;
            }

            // Does the name exist in List?
            boolean found = false;
            for (String name : pNames) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameToRate)) {
                    // Yes it does...
                    found = true;
                    break;  // Break out of this loop.
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                println("Invalid Entry (" + nameToRate + ")!" + LS
                      + "Can not find the name supplied! Try again..." + LS);
                nameToRate = "";
            }
        }
        //.................................................
        /* If we get to here then the name supplied
           (regarless of letter case) is in the List. */

        String rateNum = "";
        while (rateNum.isEmpty()) {
            println();
            print("Enter your rating (1 to 5 or 'c' to cancel): --> ");
            rateNum = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
            if (rateNum.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                return;
            }
            // Validate Entry...
            if (!rateNum.matches("[1-5]")) {
                println("Invalid Entry (" + rateNum + ")! Try again..." + LS);
                rateNum = "";
            }
            println();
        }

        // Set the rating.
        int rating = Integer.valueOf(rateNum);
        for (Properties p : prop.getProperties()) {
            if (p.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameToRate)) {
                int avgRating = p.getAverageRating();
                p.addRating(rating);
                println("Your rating of " + rating + " has been added to the accomodation" + LS
                      + "named '" + nameToRate + "' which has moved its overall rating" + LS
                      + "average from " + avgRating + " to an overall average rating of " + 
                        p.getAverageRating() + "." + LS + "This is based on " + 
                        p.getTotalNumberOfRatingsDone() + " rating(s) on the accomodation." + LS);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void println(Object... obj) {
        if (obj.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(obj[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void printErr(Object... obj) {
        if (obj.length > 0) {
            System.err.println(obj[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.err.println();
        }
    }

    public static void print(Object... obj) {
        if (obj.length > 0) {
            System.out.print(obj[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
}
```

The **Properties** class:

```
public class Properties {
        
    public static java.util.List<Properties> properties = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    
    private String propertyName;
    private String accomodationType;
    private String description;
    private String location;
    private double pricePerDay;
    private int averageRating = 0;
    private int totalNumberOfRatings;
    private boolean available;

    // Constructor #1
    public Properties() {   }

    // Constructor #2
    public Properties(String propertyName, String accomodationType, String description, 
                      String location, double pricePerDay, boolean available) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.accomodationType = accomodationType;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
        this.pricePerDay = pricePerDay;
        this.available = available;
    }
    
    // Getters & Setters
    public java.util.List<Properties> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public String getPropertyName() {
        return propertyName;
    }

    public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public String getAccomodationType() {
        return accomodationType;
    }

    public void setAccomodationType(String accomodationType) {
        this.accomodationType = accomodationType;
    }
   
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getPricePerDay() {
        return pricePerDay;
    }

    public void setPricePerDay(double pricePerDay) {
        this.pricePerDay = pricePerDay;
    }

    public int getAverageRating() {
        return this.averageRating;
    }

    public void addRating(int rating) {
        // Rateing is an integer value from 1 to 5. 
        // Where 1 is Bad and 5 Excellent.
        if (rating < 1) { rating = 1; }
        else if (rating > 5) { rating = 5; }
        int sum = 0, r = 0;
        for (Properties p : properties) {
            if (p.propertyName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.propertyName)) {
                r++;
                sum += rating;
            }
        }
        if (sum > 0 && r > 0) {
            this.averageRating = sum / r;
        }
        else {
            this.averageRating = rating;
        }
        this.totalNumberOfRatings++;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return propertyName + ", " + accomodationType + ", " + description + ", " 
                    + location + ", " + pricePerDay + ", " + averageRating + ", " 
                    + available;
    }
    
    public String toStringTable(Properties p, boolean... addHeader) {
        boolean applyHeader = false;
        if (addHeader.length > 0) {
            applyHeader = addHeader[0];
        }
        String symbol = java.util.Currency.getInstance(java.util.Locale.getDefault()).getSymbol();
        String header = "", underline = "", ls = System.lineSeparator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        header = String.format("%-18s %-10s %-50s %-10s %-10s %-8s %-6s%n", "BNB Name", 
                "BNB Type", "BNB Description", "Location", "Price/Day", "Rating", "Avail.");
        underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "=")) + ls;
        if (applyHeader) {
            sb.append(header).append(underline);
        }
        String[] desc = p.description.split("\\s+");
        java.util.List<String> descTmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("");
        for (String str : desc) {
            if ((sb2.toString() + " " + str).length() > 50) {
                descTmp.add(sb2.toString());
                sb2.setLength(0);
            }
            if (!sb2.toString().isEmpty()) {
                sb2.append(" ");
            }
            sb2.append(str);
        }
        if (!sb2.toString().isEmpty()) {
            descTmp.add(sb2.toString());
        }
        sb.append(String.format("%-18s %-10s %-50s %-12s " + symbol + "%-10.2f %-7s %-6s", 
                p.propertyName, p.accomodationType, descTmp.get(0), p.location, 
                p.pricePerDay, p.averageRating, (p.available ? "Yes" : "No")));
        
       
        if (descTmp.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < descTmp.size(); i++) {
                sb.append(ls).append(String.format("%-18s %-10s %-50s %-12s %-10s %-7s %-6s", 
                "  ","  ", descTmp.get(i), "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "));
            }
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String[] getAllPropertyNames() {
        java.util.List<String> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties prop : properties) {
            // Make sure names retrieved are Unique (DISTINCT)
            if (!tmp.contains(prop.propertyName)) {
                tmp.add(prop.propertyName);
            }
        }
        return tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
    } 
    
    public String[] getAllAccomodationTypes() {
        java.util.List<String> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties prop : properties) {
            // Make sure accomodations retrieved are Unique (DISTINCT)
            if (!tmp.contains(prop.accomodationType)) {
                tmp.add(prop.accomodationType);
            }
        }
        return tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
    }
    
    public java.util.List<Properties> getPropertiesByLocation(String location) {
        java.util.List<Properties> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties p : Properties.properties) {
            if (p.location.equalsIgnoreCase(location) && !tmp.contains(p)) {
                tmp.add(p);
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    
    public java.util.List<Properties> getPropertiesByAccomodationType(String accomodationType) {
        java.util.List<Properties> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties p : Properties.properties) {
            if (p.accomodationType.equalsIgnoreCase(accomodationType) && !tmp.contains(p)) {
                tmp.add(p);
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    
    public java.util.List<Properties> getPropertiesByRating(int rating) {
        java.util.List<Properties> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties p : Properties.properties) {
            if (p.averageRating == rating && !tmp.contains(p)) {
                tmp.add(p);
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
          
    public int getTotalNumberOfRatingsDone() {
        return this.totalNumberOfRatings;
    }
    
    public String[] getAllDescriptions() {
        java.util.List<String> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties prop : properties) {
            // Make sure descriptions retrieved are Unique (DISTINCT)
            if (!tmp.contains(prop.description)) {
                tmp.add(prop.description);
            }
        }
        return tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
    }    
    
    public String[] getAllLocations() {
        java.util.List<String> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties prop : properties) {
            // Make sure locations retrieved are Unique (DISTINCT)
            if (!tmp.contains(prop.location)) {
                tmp.add(prop.location);
            }
        }
        return tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
    }    
    
    public double[] getAllPerDayPrices() {
        java.util.List<Double> tmp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        for (Properties prop : properties) {
            // Make sure locations retrieved are Unique (DISTINCT)
            if (!tmp.contains(prop.pricePerDay)) {
                tmp.add(prop.pricePerDay);
            }
        }
        
        // Convert List<Double> to double[]...
        double[] prices = new double[tmp.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++) {
            prices[i] = tmp.get(i);
        }
        return prices;
    }    
       
}
```